A movie maybe from the 70’s about people being turned to dust out in the sunlight
I remember a girl or boy going outside looking for other people and all they find is clothes on the ground and the bodies have turned to dust.  It might be set out in the desert.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EmptyPilesOfClothing (warning, TV Tropes links are hazardous to your free time) may be handy, although it covers the empty clothing, not necessarily turning to dust.

Can you recall some of the actors? Did it feel like a TV movie, minimal budget etc.? If it is Where have all the people gone?, Peter Graves of Mission: impossible fame was acting in it.

@FuzzyBoots "warning, TV Tropes links are hazardous to your free time" is a severe understatement! I absolutely refuse to click on that link, because if I do, that's my day gone. Also, I know I'm about to click on that link.

@yshavit It also assumes that you don't know TV Tropes yet, and that you therefore still have free time left.

I have seen a recent netflix series where the people turn to dust in a virtual reality, which is a test for enrolment into Alien services.

@RohitGupta do you mean The Three Body Problem? If so they aren't dust, just dehydrated flattened husks.

Would this be Where Have All The People Gone?
IMDB's synopsis describes it as:
After a catastrophic solar flare decimates almost all life, reducing people to powdery substance, a group of survivors treks across the devastated Earth
It's 1974, so definitely within your date range.

It's a little out of the date scope, but Night of the Comet is a classic example of the protagonists finding that everyone else (as it turns out, not everyone) has been turned to dust.

Night of the Comet is a 1984 American science fiction comedy horror film written and directed by Thom Eberhardt. It stars Catherine Mary Stewart, Robert Beltran, and Kelli Maroney as survivors of a comet that has turned most people into either dust or zombies.

....

The next morning, a reddish haze covers the sky; there are no signs of life but piles of red dust and heaps of clothing everywhere. Unaware that anything has occurred, Larry goes outside and is killed by a zombie. After trying to beat DMK's high score, Reggie looks for Larry outside, mistaking the red sky as bad smog. She quickly encounters the zombie, but escapes on Larry's motorcycle. At home, she finds her sister. The two surmise that because they both spent the night in steel containers, they were saved from the comet's effects.


Trailer



It isn't set in a desert, but the constant red haze from the comet's dust trail might lead you to think that it was.

The trailer doesn't show the critical frame (due to spoilers).  I think the asker might be thinking of this image (spoiler alert) (which you're welcome to include in your answer)

Done. Thank you.
